# Bash: Replace word with spaces equal to the length of the word

Tags: string, bash, parameter-expansion

I thought my bash-fu was strong enough but apparently it isn't. I can't seem to figure this out. I would like to do something like this:

```
  var="XXXX This is a line"
  word_to_replace="XXXX"
  # ...do something
  echo "Done:${var}"
  Done:     This is a line
```

Basically I want to quickly replace all characters in a word with spaces, preferably in one step. Note, if it makes things easier `var` currently will be at the start of the string although it may have leading spaces (which would need to be retained).

In python I would possibly do this:

```
>>> var="XXXX This is a line"
>>> word_to_replace="XXXX"
>>> var=var.replace(word_to_replace, ' '*len(word_to_replace))
>>> print("Done:%s" % var)
Done:     This is a line
```

Comment: is it mandatory to pad the final string with spaces?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes. I'd like to *replace* the word with spaces equal to the length of the word, like the title mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it, using a combination of shell parameter expansion and the sed command.

```
$ var="XXXX This is a line"
$ word_to_replace="XXXX"
$ replacement=${word_to_replace//?/ }
$ sed "s/$word_to_replace/$replacement/" <<<"$var"
     This is a line
```

`?` matches any character and `${var//find/replace}` does a global substitution, so the variable `$replacement` has the same length as `$word_to_replace`, but is composed solely of spaces.

You can save the result to a variable in the usual way:

```
new_var=$(sed "s/$word_to_replace/$replacement/" <<<"$var")
```

Comment: You don't need `sed`, and it can be surprising if `$word_to_replace` includes slashes or some special characters like, dots, asterisks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In plain Bash:

If we know the word to be replaced:

```
$ line=" foo and some"
$ word=foo
$ spaces=$(printf "%*s" ${#word} "")
$ echo "${line/$word/$spaces}"
     and some
```

If we don't, we could pick the string apart to find the leading word, but this gets a bit ugly:

```
xxx() {
   shopt -s extglob              # for *( )
   local line=$1
   local indent=${line%%[^ ]*}   # the leading spaces
   line=${line##*( )}            # remove the leading spaces
   local tail=${line#* }         # part after first space 
   local head=${line%% *}        # part before first space...
   echo "$indent${head//?/ } $tail"  # replace and put back together
}
$ xxx "  word on a line"
        on a line
```

That also fails if there is only one word on the line, `head` and `tail` both get set to that word, we'd need to check for if there is a space and handle the two cases separately.

Answer (score 0):

I use GNU Awk:

```
echo "$title" | gawk '{gsub(/./, "*"); print}'
```

This replaces each character with an asterisk.

**EDIT.** Consolidated answer:

```
$ export text="FOO hello"
$ export sub="FOO"
$ export space=${sub//?/ }
$ echo "${text//$sub/$space}"
    hello
```

Comment: This replaces every character with an asterisk, which is not what has been asked and which can be implemented much easier with `tr -c '' '*'`

Comment: Then apply `tr` or whatever to `$word_to_replace` and use bash string substitution.

Comment: BTW, `tr -c '' '*'` will replace new line as well if any.

Comment: If you removed the awk option and all the `export`s from the bash option, possibly adding some explanation, then this would be the best option in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

word_to_replace="XXXX"
var="$word_to_replace This is a line"

echo "Done: $var"

word_to_replace=$(echo "$word_to_replace" | sed 's,., ,g')
var="$word_to_replace This is a line"
echo "Done: $var"
```

Comment: This appears like an answer but isn't exactly what I was looking for because it recreates the line rather than replace the word. For instance if the line had leading spaces before the word to replace, like I mentioned in the question, how would this solution be adapted ? Good approach tho', I might have to do it this way -- split the line, replace all characters in the word with space and recreate the line.

Comment: `newline=${oldline//$word_to_replace/$replacement}`

Comment: @Igor ehe ...what would `$replacement` be ?

Comment: `replacement=${word_to_replace//?/ }` from below.

Comment: @Igor you misunderstood the question. With what you suggest `${word_to_replace}` will be replaced with a *single* space. The question was about replacing all characters with as many spaces as the length of `${word_to_replace}`

Comment: No. Did you actually try the thing: `${foo//?/*}`.